# How to access audio format of user response given to Alexa for Further use

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

After user give respond to Alexa we capture that in slots, then how can we access that responses in audio format directly in Alexa skill?

For example : User -> run survey skill , Alexa -> Sure , first tell me how are you? , User -> Well, I am doing good.

In this example i want to access audio format of user response " Well, I am doing good." in raw audio format without speech-to-text processing with original tone and sarcasm of user for further use.

```
user_response = context.request.intent.slots["user_response"].value

# Generate a TTS audio response.
tts_audio_response = ask_sdk_core.speech.synthesize(user_response)

# Return the TTS audio response to Alexa.
response = context.response
```

I tried this code but how can i access it not getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your skill can access the user's raw audio input or any of its emotion / tone / metadata.  Skill input is limited to the intent that the input matched and a text representation of any slot values they provided.